# Import Angular Component into another Component by specifying the component name as input parameter

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components, angular-template

I would like to create an angle component that consists of several sub-components. Eventually I want to create a large reusable tree component whose nodes have different data types. For each data type, the tree component imports sub-components that specify how the node should be displayed. The user should be able to specify a custom component to override the default component for a particular data type. An import syntax like this would be nice:

```
<app-tree [customDateComp]="CustomDateComponent"></app-tree>
```

This could be the simplified tree.component.html:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!customDateComp">
 <app-default-date></app-default-date>
</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="customDateComp">
 {{ customDateComp }}
</ng-container>
```

Of course this does not work yet, because the components are imported with the  syntax. The approach below does not work either, because angular escapes it:

```
<app-tree [customDateComp]="'<app-custom-date></app-custom-date>'"></app-tree>
```

The sample code can be found here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xghj5f?file=src/app/app.component.html

Does anyone have an idea how to import Angular Components into other Components by specifying the component name as an input parameter? Or is there a better way to override default sub-components of a third-party component? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have a look at `ng-content` think that will do what you need

Comment: maybe [dynamic-component-loader](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use/create dynamic template to compile dynamic Component with Angular 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma638844206433166?file=src/app/tree/tree.component.ts) working.

Among the possible approaches, there is a portal (and the utilities available from `@angular/cdk/portal`).

Basically, this is what you need:

**1 - A placeholder (in this case, `cdkPortalOutlet` setup) for the received component:**

```html
<ng-template [cdkPortalOutlet]="_compPortal"></ng-template>
```

**2 - A portal (`_compPortal`, above) to plug into your portal outlet:**

```
_compPortal = new ComponentPortal<any>(MyCustomComponent);
```

That's all.

#### In your case (the stackblitz you've linked in your question) you can do:

**0 - Import `@angular/cdk/portal` module:**

```js
import {PortalModule} from '@angular/cdk/portal';

@NgModule({imports: [ ... PortalModule ] ...}) export class AppModule { }
```

**1 - tree.component.html**

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="!_compPortal">
 <app-date></app-date>
</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="_compPortal">
  <ng-template [cdkPortalOutlet]="_compPortal"></ng-template>
</ng-container>
```

**2 - tree.compoenent.ts**

```js
@Input() 
set customDateComp(customComp: any){
  this._compPortal = customComp ? new ComponentPortal(customComp) : null;
}
_compPortal: ComponentPortal<any>;
```

**3 - app.component.ts**

```js
// Notice this is not `_comp: CustomDateComponent`.
// I'm setting up an attribute that receives the type so I can 
// make it available on the template
_comp = CustomDateComponent;
```

**4 - app.component.html**

```html
<app-tree [customDateComp]="_comp"></app-tree>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dynamic component loader https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader